# react native config cannot read env file in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-config

I have follow the doc: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#ios
until: Availability in Build settings and Info.plist
step 6. create new build phase for the scheme which will generate `"tmp.xcconfig"` before each build exposing values to Build Settings and Info.plist (this snippet has to be placed after `"echo ... > tmp/envfile"` if approach explained below is used)

- I have created schema for my app then in build -> pre-actions. I click add new script and paste the following:

```
echo ".env.staging" > /tmp/envfile
"${SRCROOT}/../node_modules/react-native-config/ios/ReactNativeConfig/BuildXCConfig.rb" "${SRCROOT}/.." "${SRCROOT}/tmp.xcconfig"
```

- then I go to info.plist and use $(MYENVVAR) to get value from .env file but it could not get any value.
  Has anyone ever faced it?
  my package json lock is `"react-native-config": "0.11.7"`

Happy to see any comments

Comment: I notice that the docs you mentioned  https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#ios  and the version you have installed are mismatched.

Comment: How I can check if there are mismatched version?

Comment: I too have tried installing the config file as per the above document, it works fine with Android platform but IOS facing the same issue as said above Client Id or other Api urls are not being fetched from .env file and value passed is undefined.

Comment: Also found a open issue for the repo https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/444

Answer (score 7):

If you can see empty config file in your JS when importing `import Config from 'react-native-config'` and if you are using Pods
just add (without `react-native link react-native-config`)

```
pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config/react-native-config.podspec'
```

in your Podfile.

And try to update module version

```
"react-native-config": "^1.0.0"
```